# Resizing LayeredPane Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have a JPanel that uses BorderLayout and contains a jTable and a layeredPane. I need to use the layeredPane because it contains a jComboBox on top of a jTextPane. The problem is that when the user resizes the screen, the layeredPane doesn't resize. How can i fix this? I have something like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new Borderlayout());
MyTable table = new MyTable(); 
panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
//addind things in the layered pane
panel.add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Using a layout manager for the layered pane won't work, because i need components to be overlapped.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have posted JLayeredPane takes the SOUTH (BorderLayout.PAGE_END) place in the panel with BorderLayout. That means that the component in CENTER will take **all** additional space offered to the panel. And you have your table in CENTER.

Just place JLayeredPane in the CENTER and table in the NORTH to let the pane take all additional space.

More on BorderLayout:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

You also might want to read more on Swing layouts:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: Actually I already have another component in the north. And my problem is not that the JLayeredPane has too little space, but the opposite, when it is resized it takes up all the space, making the north and the center components disappear. Also, when it is resized some of the components of the JLayeredPane are no longer visible. I already red those tutorials, but couldn't find anything to help me.

Comment: Then you should post a complete code example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) that represents your problem, otherwise i cannot help.

Answer (score 1):

- common issue about JLayeredPane is that its childs would be placed by setBounds, because doesn't supports Standards LayoutManagers excluding Null Layout
- have to add ComponentListener on event componentResized to change JPanels Bounds
- for JComponents placed to the JPanel to use Standard LayoutManager
- more than an alternative is to use the proper JLayer for Java7 based on custom JXLayer for Java6